# Why does my MVC razor view does not want to instantiate a ResourceManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I'm writing this code on an MVC 3 view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@SecondIndexStrings.Activity_ActivityName</th>
        <th>@SecondIndexStrings.Activity_DateStarted</th>
        <th>@SecondIndexStrings.Activity_ProficiencyLevel</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var activity in Model.Activities)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@activity.ActivityName</td>
            <td>@activity.DateStarted.ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td>@new ResourceManager(typeof(IndexStrings)).GetString(activity.ProficiencyLevel.ToString())</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

For some reason the line with "@new ResourceManager..." is not recognized as valid and it gives me a Compilation Error whenever I run it.

If I only write @ResourceManager the text turns blue indicating that is recognized as a valid class, the same for the IndexStrings resource but, with the whole thing it seems that it doesn't know that those are supposed to be classes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the white-space, you must use parenthesis to help it see where your expression starts/ends:

```
@(new ResourceManager(typeof(IndexStrings)).GetString(activity.ProficiencyLevel.ToString()))
```

You might also want to consider adding a helper method, perhaps as an extension-method on `HtmlHelper`, so you can use something like:

```
@Html.Resource<IndexStrings>(activity.ProficiencyLevel)
```

or similar, which might look something like:

```
public static string Resource<T>(this HtmlHelper html, object key) {
    return new ResourceManager(typeof(T)).GetString(key.ToString());
}
```